# 50K, what to do with it?

Tags: loans, student

I'm 26 and a double masters student in transportation planning and engineering. I have received 50k in settlement money; I don’t know what’s the best course of action with this money. Im looking at 56,000 in student loans at 6% APR over 10 years. I graduate in two years, then, upon finding a job, I expect a minimum starting salary of 50k. I earn a small stipend from an internship, about 800 a month. I pay 550 in rent. Should I invest or should I try to reduce the loan? Should I save it all and worry about it when I graduate? Should I buy a condo and rent it to other students?

Comment: If you think you can invest it and get more than 6%, invest it. Otherwise pay off the student loan. Be sure to save some as a buffer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to do with sudden wealth?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/15784/what-to-do-with-sudden-wealth)

Comment: Are your loans subsidized?

Comment: Are you currently making loan payments, or do your loan payments start after you finish school?

Comment: @Tvde1: If you think you can invest it and get more than 6%, especially sufficiently more for the risk to have value, you're a fool.

Comment: Have you received 50,000 U.S. dollars, 50,000 pounds, 50,000 yen, 50,000 Australian dollars, 50,000 rupees... ?  Asking because the value of each of those is rather different, which would affect what you could do with the money.

Comment: @Sean - I don't see that it really matters, OP has given the amount they received, loan amount, expected salary, current income, and a good metric of current expenses. It could be in any of the denominations you listed and not matter.

Comment: Is your student loan accumulating interest while you are in graduate school, or do you have a waiver until you leave graduate school?  If no interest is accumulating, then you might put the money into a high-yield savings account for now and plan to use it later to payoff the loan.

Comment: Before putting all of your money toward the loan or in some sort of financial instrument, maybe read [Is there a good rule of thumb for how much I should set aside as emergency cash](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/83/is-there-a-good-rule-of-thumb-for-how-much-i-should-have-set-aside-as-emergency)?

Answer (score 31):

**Reduce your loan.**

Currently, stocks are especially in United States rather highly valued. If you subtract taxes, you probably won't exceed 6% per year over 10 years. By reducing the loan, you are having an investment that guarantees 6% return.

See your situation like this: you have an investment with 6% guaranteed return. Most people don't. Now invest in the guaranteed return!

Comment: Student loans typically don't accrue interest while the student is still in school so they may as well hold on to it and make it at least grow in the pathetically slow way money grows when you don't want to lose it. At least until they have to start paying down the loan.

Comment: @Daniel My student loan certainly added the interest to the loan while I was at school. Besides, why would a bank give a student loan for free without interest? They could calculate that later the student pays lots of interest, but then again there would be an incentive to change the loan to another bank who didn't give loans for free and thus charges less interest after graduation...

Comment: @juhist In the US, many student loans are _subsidized_, meaning that the federal government pays the interest. From the borrowers' point of view, no interest is being charged to _them_.

Comment: @DStanley Oh. That indeed means they money should be invested for a short term (into bonds) and then after graduation used to reduce the loan. Where I live (Eurozone), bond yields are negative but bank accounts do not charge negative interest so if student loans were interest-free where I live, I would save the money to a bank account.

Comment: I would be careful saying that [stocks are highly valued](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/117551/dont-invest-now-because-the-market-is-high).  Maybe change or remove that first sentence, as it implies trying to time the market is good advice.

Comment: But it's true that stocks are highly valued: https://www.multpl.com/shiller-pe -- stocks are a wonderful investment, even today, but we all need to understand that while long-term yields used to be 8% before taxes, today they are more like 7% before taxes. If stock valuation was low, they could yield perhaps even 9% in the long term, meaning stock investment return could after taxes exceed 6%.

Comment: Most students who borrow in the U.S. have both subsidized and unsubsidized loans. The unsubsidized loans do collect interest as soon as they are dispersed so it may be worthwhile to pay those off ASAP but the subsidized loans won't gain interest till 6 months after leaving school.

Answer (score 25):

Don't buy a condo, that would be kind of a horrible idea, even if you can qualify.

If it was me, I would stick it in a boring savings account, something like Ally.  Once you graduate, get settled in potentially a new location, I would use the money to pay off your student loan.  Until then, the money becomes an insurance policy to make sure you have enough money to graduate.

Your best investment, right now, is yourself.  What can you do to raise your future income?

Comment: He's already a double major with an internship. What more is he going to do to raise his income??

Comment: @corsiKa I got the impression that the last paragraph was referring to the last sentence of the previous paragraph: "... the money becomes an insurance policy to make sure you ... graduate".  Implying that ensuring he graduates is what he can do to raise his future income.

Comment: There are accounts that pay higher than Ally. Spend some time looking for them if you go in this direction.

Comment: I really like this answer, 6% interest on the student loans over a few years isn't a huge game change in the long run, since OP can graduate, theoretically land a high(er) paying job, & then pay the loans off w the existing money, it wouldn't all be loss either as Ally interest will pay a bit back over that time too.  A CD that lets you do a few withdrawals might be something to look at, but right now the rate difference between Ally Savings and a CD in that amount is probably less than half a point.

Comment: @Mehrdad what are some of these accounts? Ally is 1.7% which is already pretty good. The only higher one I've seen is Simple at 2.1% but that requires a ton of micromanagement, and Wealthfront at 1.83%, but it's not a savings account you can easily pay bills out of.

Comment: @hmmm: Just one example: ETFCU gives 3.3% on up to $20k. I don't want to list them all but you can find other ones if you just spend a few minutes Googling. ;)

Answer (score 3):

juhist has a good answer, but it's only part of a full answer.

## Saving

You should save a couple thousand so you don't rack up credit card or other debt due to everyday living expenses plus unexpected bills. You don't want to go broke because of car repair, health care bills, or something else you might not be able to predict or prevent. What you make after college is future money. You don't have it now so don't count on it now. Banking on future money is how most people stay broke for their whole lives.

## Income

Also, no matter how good you are in school, you won't get $50k right out of graduation. You don't have the experience dozens of other applicants applying for the same jobs have. If you get lucky, or you already have an agreements in place, you might be able to turn your internship into a job, but without that prior agreement in hand, that's not guaranteed either. When I was in high school, I was told that going into a career in computers was a guarantee to get a minimum of $45k a year job right out of college. That was just over 20 years ago. Because of a wide variety of things, such as the stock market and a flood of other people doing the same thing, I didn't make half that for years after going to college. In fact, because of various reasons that I'm not going to share, I didn't get to $45k until about 3-4 years ago.

You might have to get a lower paying job for a year or more before you get your first "real" job in your industry. Finding a job takes a lot of time and effort. Unless you are absolutely at the top of your field and are well known for your work, you aren't likely to see anyone waiting to give you a job when you graduate. It's a hard pill to swallow, but it's unfortunately the truth for the vast majority of us.

## Education

You getting a double masters might help, but it might not. My mom and one of my sisters both have masters degrees and it didn't help them. I have another sister that has multiple masters and bachelors degrees and she's decently well off. Just having a masters doesn't guarantee anything. What you do with it and are willing to do to make it matter matters much more.

My one sister that's using her advanced education got it while in the military, so they paid for most of it and she also has massive experience in those fields. She can literally get any job in her field because of her experience *and* her education.

One of my brothers-in-law has an advanced degree that his job paid for. I don't remember what it is, but he spent years getting it while working full-time. A couple years ago, he got "reduced" from his upper management job when the company was bought, and hasn't found a replacement job since, due to how specialized his position was. He's now doing a travelling maintenance job that probably pays less than half what he used to get. It's a lot less stress and he likes it, but it's not what he was told would happen when he was getting his degree.

## Getting to the real answer

The general recommendation is to have 3-12 months worth of living expenses saved in case of emergencies. What number of months you pick depends on how stable you think your income is. Getting $800 a month and then paying $550 in rent leaves only $250 a month, which isn't very much. In fact, that's less than most people pay in groceries a month for a single person, not to mention eating out any, paying utilities, car insurance, gas, and a dozen other bills that are easy enough to incur. Even if you take public transportation, those fares can add up.

If you already have credit card debt or a car loan, pay them off first with what you decide not to save. If you have any other debt, pay that next.

## Student loans

Student loans have a variety of ways to defer payments. Not to mention that in the US, they are specifically not allowed to be predatory lenders by law, unlike other debt collectors. Also, student loans are considered differently on your credit history than most of the rest of your debt. You should still want to clear out student loans as fast as possible, but not to the detriment of your health or even other debts. And having a long term loan on your credit history that you are on good terms with (paying regularly or otherwise not defaulting on) is actually beneficial to your credit report. Yes, it means that your debt to credit ratio is affected, but it shows that you are a good debt risk since you are actually paying your loans. Also, deferring your student loans doesn't show up on your credit report, except that you are still in good standing with your student loan creditor.

I've gone through hell with my student loans to where I've been 180+ days late. I finally talked to the creditor and got one of the many deferments they offer and my credit report suddenly said I was in good standing the very next month. The credit reporting agencies don't care about that type of detail in a report, they go off what the creditor says about the loan, and if the creditor is happy with the state of the loan, so is the credit report.

People talk about student loans being a noose around their neck. Sometimes this is true, but it also ignores all of the other debt they have, which oftentimes happens to be a boulder holding them to the bottom of their river of debt. Because student loans are so forgiving and flexible, you should pay them off last*. Once you start getting bills for them, keep paying them on time and the full amount, but always consider that the other loans you'll have to take out are always going to be worse to deal with if you default on them than student loans. Default on a vehicle loan and they repossess it. Default on your house or apartment, and they kick you out.

*The only thing that should be fully paid off after your student loans is a house/condo. Make sure that your future monthly mortgage payment is paid in full before paying the monthly student loans, though. Also, paying more on your mortgage than the minimums will save you thousands by the time you pay it off. Because of the difference in size of loans, the savings of paying more on your house vs paying more on your student loans weights in favor of paying more to the mortgage.

## More budgeting information

If you want more information about budgeting and how to deal with money, you can't go wrong with the book "[America's Cheapest Family Gets You Right on the Money](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0307339459)". I'm not affiliated with this book or family in any way, I'm just another satisfied customer. They go into a lot of detail about how to budget your money as well as how to deal with loans and creditors.

Answer (score 2):

We don't have enough info for this specific situation, but here's a checklist to follow:

1. **Emergency fund**

Depending on the difficulty of finding a job, save 3-6 months of living expenses.

2. **High-interest debt**

Credit cards, personal loans, anything over 10% APR needs to be reconciled immediately.

3. **Tax-advantaged accounts**

After high-interest debt, you should start looking into tax-advantaged accounts. A 401k is typically better if you plan to retire with little extra income, and a Roth is typically better if you want to retire with a large amount every month (You will be limited by how much you make, be sure to check with a registered financial advisor, as this information can't be taken as investment advice.)

4. (optional) **Other investments**

This one highly depends on what you know, but if you think you can do real estate, then go for it. Typically, condos are bad investments, so be sure to do plenty of research if you decide to go that route.

5. **Pay off student loans**

You can defer student loans in a ton of different ways, so this is a really low priority to hit. That being said, if you don't have anything else that can make you more money, then paying off your student loan early is guaranteed money.